# Node.js in LibGDX project

Tags: java, libgdx, javascript, node.js, socket

I'm developing a game with LibGDX, and right now I'm trying the multiplayer part. I have managed to connect several players through Node.js and socketIO but when I try to make the lobby I am doubting if it's correct to use this.

I have read that it's oriented to web applications, so my question is: Is it advisable to use it with Java? Should I change it?

Thank you for reading and forgive my bad english.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/realtime-multi-player-game-design-principles-for-node-js?rq=1